# 'MD5 is not a known hash algorithm' exception while trying to upload a blob to Azure Cloud?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, cloud, md5, shared-access-signatures

I'm trying to upload a file in Azure by using a SAS token but I receive this error while I try to upload the file :

> MD5 is not a known hash algorithm

I have these 2 methods that I use, one to generate the file link which will be used to upload the file:

```
   public string GetBlobSASUploadFileLink(string fileName)
   {
            var connectionString = string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}", StorageAccountName, AccessKey);
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(FilesContainer);

            SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
            sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);
            sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create;

            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            return string.Format("{0}{1}", blob.Uri, blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints));
   }
```

And this method where also the exception is thrown, which should upload the file in Azure:

```
 public async Task UploadFilesToBlob(string fileLink, IBrowserFile file)
 {
        try
        {
            var cloudBlockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(fileLink));
            await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.OpenReadStream(912000000));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
  }
```

In this second method in the `UploadFromStreamAsync` method the exception is thrown.
I'm guessing the framework uses the MD5 algorithm but the Azure uses another cryptographic hashing algorithm but I don't know what should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow the official sample code and test it, it works fine. You can refer my test code.

**Test Result:**

[image]

[image]

***Sample code like below:***

```
    public static async Task MyFunc()
    {
        var filepath = @"C:\Users\jason\Desktop\1.txt";
        var file = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open);

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;

        string container_name = "memorydumps";
        var policyName = "Pan";

        var connectionString = string.Format("DefaultEndpoi***;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(container_name);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        var storedPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create |
              SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read
        };
        var permissions = container.GetPermissions();

        // optionally clear out any existing policies on this container
        permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Clear();
        // add in the new one
        permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add(policyName, storedPolicy);
        // save back to the container
        container.SetPermissions(permissions);

        //reading file name & file extention    
        string file_extension = Path.GetExtension(filepath);
        string filename_withExtension = Path.GetFileName(filepath);

        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename_withExtension);
        cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = file_extension;
        await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file);
        var returnpath = string.Format("{0}{1}", cloudBlockBlob.Uri, cloudBlockBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(storedPolicy));
        Console.WriteLine(returnpath);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer helped me resolve the issue. I was using an outdated nuget package: Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob instead of Azure.Storage.Blobs and the exception was thrown from the System.Security.Cryptography, I belive because there was a different enum type used in the old azure package compared to the enum used in the Cryptography package.